# Google Webmaster data quality issues

Tags: google-api, google-search-console, google-api-webmasters

I am running into a weird error.

We have a standard implementation of getting data from searchconsole and storing it in a database. We have crosschecked the data during the implementation and it was good.

Lately we have seen huge differences in what is reported in search console and the data retrieved from the API. In some cases it is only 10% lower than the search console data but in some cases the API data shows 50% less than what is being reported in the search console.

Is any one aware of these issues and has anyone run into this recently?

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem for about a month now and finally fixed this issue.

This was my original request

```
service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv, 'webmasters', 'v3', __doc__, __file__,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters.readonly')
```

I have fixed it by removing the **".readonly"** on the end. This was causing me to get sampled data.

My scope now looks like this and return full results.

```
service, flags = sample_tools.init(
      argv, 'webmasters', 'v3', __doc__, __file__,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/webmasters')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue of reconciling to the console. How are you storing the data, i.e. your database table structure?

Have you read about the differences in the aggregation between page and property? These can cause discrepancies.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6155685?hl=en#urlorsite

For example a search query that returns multiple pages aggregated by the property counts as 1 impression. When you group by pages this would show as however many pages you have in the search results e.g. 3 or 4. Therefore by query and by date your impressions will be lower than if you aggregate by page.